# How to delete a column after applying styler function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

How to delete column after applying styler? Here's my style function:

```
def highlight_late(x):
        c1 = 'background-color: red'
        #condition
        m = x['price_1'] < x['price_main_x']
        m2 = x['price_2'] < x['price_main_x']
        m3 = x['price_3'] < x['price_main_x']
        #empty DataFrame of styles
        df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    

    
#set column price_2 by condition
df1.loc[m, 'price_1'] = c1
df1.loc[m2, 'price_2'] = c1
df1.loc[m3, 'price_3'] = c1
df1.loc[m, 'url_x'] = c1
df1.loc[m2, 'url_y'] = c1
df1.loc[m3, 'url'] = c1

return df1
```

Method below return me TypeError: 'Styler' object does not support item deletion

```
styles = myDF.style.apply(highlight_late, axis=None)
del styles['price_1']
del styles['price_2']
del styles['price_3']
styles.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

i also try:

```
mydf.style.hide_columns(['price_1', 'price_2', 'price_3']).to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

its not work, columns wont hide.

even this simple script from https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_columns.html wont work

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
df.style.hide_columns(["a", "b"])
df.to_excel('test2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 4):

From `pandas v1.4.0` use [`.hide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html) with `axis='columns'`. [`.hide_columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_columns.html) is deprecated.

---

Try `hide_columns`:

```
styles = myDF.style.hide_columns(['price_1', 'price_2', 'price_3']).apply(highlight_late, axis=None)
```

Or delete them:

```
styles = myDF.style.hide_columns(['price_1', 'price_2', 'price_3'])
styles = styles.apply(highlight_late, axis=None)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the columns you want to write into Excel instead.

```
cols = [col for col in styles.columns if col == condition]
df.to_excel('test2.xlsx', columns=cols)
```

Comment: This seems buggy... by excluding some columns, the styler formatting did not shift along with the excluded columns. So the styling that remained did not correspond to the data for the remaining columns.

Comment: Worked two years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Styler.hide()` function available from `pandas version 1.4.0`. Check the last line from the example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
# apply any style to the dataframe
styler = df.style.apply(highlight_late, axis=None)

# now if you want to hide the column(s) from the styler
styler = styler.hide(['a', 'b'], axis=1)
```